# Run a function on all rows in pandas dataframe and create a new one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

| text | number |
| --- | --- |
| hello a b c | 12 |
| text c d e | 13 |
| hello z b c | 45 |
| small type | 36 |

I have a function called **calc**.

This function takes two strings and returns a number. I need to do this for all of the rows. In case the number returned is 1 I need to remove only the first string (first row), drop the second one, but add it's number to the number of the first row.

Let's say the function would return 1 only for 1st and 2nd row, in that case I need to get a dataframe that looks like this:

| text | number |
| --- | --- |
| hello a b c | 25 |
| hello z b c | 45 |
| small type | 36 |

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What if the function returns 1 for the 1st and 2nd row and also for the 2nd and 3rd row? Would you still drop the 2nd row and keep the 3rd row (because the 2nd row has already been dropped before you can calculate the function)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `shift` to combine data from each row with the next row, like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"text": ["hello a b c", "text c d e", "hello z b c", "small type"],
                   "number": [12, 13, 45, 36]})

def calc(a, b): # example for illustration of what calc might contain
    if a == "hello a b c" and b == "text c d e":
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

# Make a column containing the text in the next row
df["text_+1"] = df["text"].shift(-1)

# Apply the calc function, taking the text on each row and the next as parameters
df["calc_result"] = df.apply(lambda row: calc(row["text"], row["text_+1"]), axis=1)

# Where calc_result is 1, add the number from the next row
df.loc[df["calc_result"] == 1, "number"] += df["number"].shift(-1)

# Filter out rows where calc_result on the previous row is 1
df = df[df["calc_result"].shift() != 1]
```